# Not able to decode escaped strings python

Tags: python, json

I fetched some JSON data through python and I'm getting a dictionary. The data is escaped, so I've got a string like:

```
https:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_banners\\/2604140473\\/1404508267
```

Unfortunately, following the method to decode `"".decode("string-escape")` doesn't work, nor using underscode, or instead of string, unicode... I don't know how it should be, I just tried what I found here. If I encode it, it returns the following:

```
'https:\\\\/\\\\/pbs.twimg.com\\\\/profile_banners\\\\/2604140473\\\\/1404508267'
```

It's like if the data were already decoded and treated as literal string and not as a escaped one.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Can you post part of the original json? Also how are you decoding it? Are you using the standard json module? If you are, then it's likely that the data itself is simply escaped too many times at the source - in that situation you're pretty much guessing at the escaping anyway, so you could just rewrite the data with a regex like r"\(.)" -> r"\1".

Comment: could it be as simple as `s.replace('\\','')`?

Comment: @viraptor it's just a dictionary. I didn't decode it. actually I'm getting raw data from prompt just to try everything but as it was escaped I tried to decode it in python terminal.

Comment: Are you putting two slashes in the parameter in `decode()`?

Comment: @dawg Yeah! That's a good idea. Not official but logical due to the circumstances. Thank you very much. I'll accept it if you post it as an answer.

Comment: I don't think `decode("string_escape")` would work here as doing so would only escape `"\\/"` to `"\/"` which further cannot be escaped. dawg's solution's is probably the best

Comment: No just "string-escape". only 1. Why @Batman ?

Comment: @AshokaLella :-) Ok yeah that's the best. I told you I just tried what I was able to find, no idea about this stuff :-)

Comment: Nevermind, I just saw @dawg 's solution, and it's better than what I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be as easy as:

```
>>> tgt
'https:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_banners\\/2604140473\\/1404508267'
>>> tgt.replace('\\', '')
'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/2604140473/1404508267'
```